# Understanding the definition of Positivity Constraints in Coq

Tags: coq, calculus-of-constructions

In Interactive Theorem Proving and Program Development the authors explain constraints on constructors of inductive types in Coq.

For inductive type $T$, a constructor must have the form $t_1 \rightarrow t_2 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow t_l \rightarrow T a_1 ... a_k$ where $k$ is the number of arguments of the inductive type $T$.

There are some restrictions placed on the $t_i$s, which I cannot understand.

> If $t_i$ is the type of a constant, then $t_i$ can have the form "$g(Tb_{1,1} ... b_{1,k})...(Tb_{l,1} ... b_{l,k}),$" provided the expressions $b_{i,j}$ also satisfy the typing rules, and $T$ does not occur in these expressions or in $g$.

and

> If $t_i$ is the type of a function, this type can have the form $t_1'\rightarrow ... \rightarrow t'_m \rightarrow g(Tb_{1,1} ... b_{1,k})...(Tb_{l,1} ... b_{l,k})$ but the type $T$ cannot occur in the expressions $t'_1, ... t'_m$ or in the expressions $b_{i,j}$

I am confused on what it means for a type $t_i$ "*to have the form* of $g(Tb_{1,1} ... b_{1,k})...(Tb_{l,1} ... b_{l,k})$".

For instance, does **nat** (the type of natural numbers) *have the form* of $g(Tb_{1,1} ... b_{1,k})...(Tb_{l,1} ... b_{l,k})$"?

If so, how does **nat** obtain such a elaborate form? What is $g$ and what are the terms in the $(l,k)$ matrix $b_{i,j}$?

If not, am I prohibited from using **nat** in type constructors of inductive types? (That would seem absurd...)

Below I have uploaded a screenshot of the page in question.

[image: Interactive Theorem Proving and Program Development pg 379]

Update: I was able to construct a counterexample to the textbook:

```
Definition g := fun x y z : Type => nat.

Inductive T : Set :=
  t : (g T T T) -> T.
```

Here $l = 1, k = 0$, and $t_1$ can only have the form $g(T)$ but I was able to use $T$ 3 times inside an actual Coq environment.

Edit 2:
I think what you guys are saying about the reduced form makes sense so I tried to make another "counterexample"

```
Inductive g (x y z: Type) : Set.

Inductive T : Set :=
  t : (g T T T) -> T.
```

Comment: I think Coq reduces `g T T T` to its normal form `nat`, and then checks the resulting `t: nat -> T` which complies with the rules. The book probably does not mention this normalization step.

Answer (score 2):

Take $l = k = 0$, the matrix of $b_{ij}$'s has size $0 \times 0$, hence we do not have to defined any $b_{ij}$, and take $g = \mathbf{nat}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndrejBauer but I don't think we can choose $l, k$ aribitrarily. In fact, they are related to the terms in the constructor. So $l = 1$ since the constructor would have one argument of type **nat** and $k$ is decided by the number of arguments to the inductive type $T$.

Comment: You misunderstand the textbook. The $g$ and the $b_{ij}$ are *schematic*, i.e., they show you the *form* of syntax that can be used, and are not meant to be actual Coq code. Your counter-example reduces to `Inductive T : Set :=
  t : nat -> T` by the definition of `g` and shows nothing. You need to compare the *reduced* definition of `T` (i.e., with the definition of `g` unfolded) to the indicated forms in the textbook. But I doubt I can explain this point in a comment, unless you understand the difference between a meta-variable and a variable.

Comment: To address your comment further: I did not "choose $l$, $k$ arbitrarily". You might be confused about how to quantify $l$ and $k$. If we want to verify that some particular expression $E$ has the form $g (T b_{1,1} \ldots b_{1,k}) \cdots (T b_{l,1} \ldots b_{l,k})$ then we need to find $l, k$, the $b_{ij}$'s and the $g$ so that we end up getting $E$. Example: take $l = 1$, $k = 2$, $b_{11} = a$, $b_{12} = a$, and $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. (I purposely use strange things to emphasize that these are purely syntactic manipulations of expressions.) Then $g(T b_{11} b_{12}) = \sqrt{1 + T a a}$.

Comment: Consider the case $l = k = 0$: then $g (T b_{1,1} \ldots b_{1,k}) \cdots (T b_{l,1} \ldots b_{l,k})$ is just $g$. Furthermore, consider $g = \mathbf{nat}$. Then we get just $\mathbf{nat}$. This is precisely what you asked for: what should we take for $l$, $k$, $b_{ij}$ and $g$ so that $g (T b_{1,1} \ldots b_{1,k}) \cdots (T b_{l,1} \ldots b_{l,k})$ becomes equal to $\mathbf{nat}$. I just answered your question.

Comment: I think what you are saying about reduced definition makes sense. But I'm still confused about $l =0$. $g$ is the schematic of a type $t_i$ inside one of the arguments of a constructor for inductive type $T$. But this means that the constructor has at least one argument (namely $t_i$) and therefore $l$ (the number of $i$'s is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Put another way, the first usage of $l$ is in the expression $t_1 \rightarrow t_2 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow t_l \rightarrow T a_1 ... a_k$, and after we use it that way, there is no longer the free choice of $l$ inside $g(…)$

Comment: It is not true that the constructor must have at least one argument. When thet texbook mentions $t_1 \to t_2 \to \ldots \to t_l \to T a_1 \ldots, a_k$, it nowehere says that $l  \geq 1$. We can set $l = 0$ in which case we get just $T a_1 \ldots a_k$. And indeed you have to allow $l = 0$ in order to get inductive types with constructors that have no arguments, such as the booleans (the constructors `true` and `false` have no arguments).

Comment: I agree that $l=0$ is possible in general. But when $l=0$ we can no longer speak of $g(…)$ since $g(...)$ is the schematic of $t_i$ for some $i$. But $l=0$ mean there are actually no $t_i$'s at all.